# "gmon.out: No such file or directory" error

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, gprof

I'm trying to run gprof command on my program, but it doesn't work for some reason. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

P.S. I am worikng with Cmake(CLion IDE), I added those lines:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pg")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
```

cmd input:

```
C:\_main\Projects\tau_plus_plus\bin>gprof __tau__.exe
```

cmd output:

```
BFD: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 3772.
gmon.out: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Don't add screenshots for text. Disabled users or screenreaders may not see the images, and therefore cannot help! So in your own interest,  copy text and paste instead.

Comment: To add symbols to your object files, add option `-g` to both compiler and linker.